# sizeof(streamsize) using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, types, typedef, sizeof

According to the MSDN documentation for Visual Studio 2012, streamsize is defined as follows:

```
#ifdef _WIN64
    typedef __int64 streamsize;
#else
    typedef int streamsize;
#endif
```

However examining the actual source for iosfwd the definition appears to be as follows (note no conditional):

```
typedef _Longlong streamsize;
```

This causes sizeof(streamsize) to return 8 bytes regardless of _WIN64 definition in visual studio 2012.

In Visual Sudio 2008 by comparison has the following definition in iosfwd:

```
#ifdef _WIN64
typedef __int64 streamoff;
typedef __int64 streamsize;

#else /* _WIN64 */
typedef long streamoff;
typedef int streamsize;
#endif /* _WIN64 */
```

Note the code matches the documentation.

Given this information my question is as follows in 2 parts:

1.)  Is the MSDN documentation for streamsize in error for Visual C++ 2012?

2.)  The larger issue:  Is true backwards compatibility for 32 bit applications be slowly dropped?

Thanks!

Comment: MSVC always breaks binary compatibility between major releases.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen plenty of cases (MSDN and elsewhere) where it looks like documentation for release `X` has just been copied forward for release `X + 1`, without changes. The update to allow for 64-bit seems to have happened at the VS2005/2008 transition, even VS2013 still has the same text as VS2008.

If the documentation and the code disagree, it's the *code* that's right, since that's what gets compiled.

In terms of your *second* question, only Microsoft knows that. However, it's natural to drop support for earlier systems as time goes on. Other than IBM's mainframes, I don't know *anyone* who's done more to allow for backward compatibility than Microsoft but even they have to draw the line somewhere.

For example (from memory), Visual C++ 1.52c was the last compiler to be able to emit 16-bit code because, once the NT stream took over from 98 (forgetting the abortion that was ME for now), there was no need.

MS did their best to ensure Windows still *ran* 16-bit code but there was no real desire to keep making *new* 16-bit code.

It may well be the same case here, with 32-bit holdouts relegated to earlier releases of VS, but we can't say for certain. Who knows what evil lurks in the hearts of MS executives? :-)